# Kubuntu 20.04 LTS: Unable to complete web authentication when linking Google account as an online service

Tags: kubuntu, settings, google

I am trying to link my Google account as an online service in Kubuntu 20.01 LTS, so I can access my files and stuff through the file manager link in Ubuntu. Every time I try to sign in, the window goes blank and nothing happens. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Same for me, when I close the window it re-opens. But after providing the information, the screen is blank.

Comment: The same is happening for me